# JQuery HTTPGet and Page Refresh on ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

I'm using FileTree JQuery component to pass a directory selection to the page. I'm using HTTPGet to pass the selected file and catch it on Page_Load (so far, so good!).

After this, i want to make some changes on page and "refresh" controls.

What is the best approach to do this?

Thx!

**JQuery Function:**

```
function LoadImages(file) {
    var param = {
        "Action": "LoadImages",
        "file": escape(file)
    };

    $.getJSON("SomePage.aspx", param);
}
```

**Code-Behind (aspx.cs)**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (QueryString.Current.Get(Constants.HTTPGet.Action) == Constants.HTTPGet.LoadImages)
        {
            DoSomethingWithFile(Request["file"]);
            divAnything.Visible= true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "refresh" controls?

Comment: In my code-behind i'm binding a .net control. I need to show this change.

Comment: did you call DataBind() after you provided the data source?

Comment: In my code-behind, even a div.visible = true doesn't work...

Comment: such a change requires the site to be sent for a post-back. could you provide some code samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running when the page is not a post back.

Try taking the code segment outside the check, and see if that was the issue for you.
(ideally, you can check using breakpoints, if your code is being accessed).

i.e.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //keep this block for future use
    }

    if (QueryString.Current.Get(Constants.HTTPGet.Action) == Constants.HTTPGet.LoadImages)
    {
        divAnything.Visible= true;
    }
}
```

Always remember that if you have an action in your page, and you need the ASP.NET engine to process it, you'll need to send the page back.
In javascript, you can force a postback caling the form's submit method, or with a control that has a postback event to it.

i.e in JavaScript.

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

i.e in jQuery.

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Comment: Thx! I replaced GET by submit() + hidden field.